# ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY randomly resetting

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I've got a VPS running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS server 64bit. It works great except for this one issue, which is that ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY is reset randomly every so often and rendering a couple of the pages on the server unusable.

I've looked around for anyone with similar issues, and found non.

Mysql v5.7.12

Thanks for any help!

Comment: The sql-mode can be set at runtime, globally or per session. I would assume someone or a script (e.g. a webshop?) sets the mode explicitly, maybe uses `set sql_mode=default;`, unaware of the new 5.7. defaults. Try searching for `sql_mode` in your script files. Or maybe some client that sets that value globally? I don't think mysql resets that value randomly by itself. And I assume you don't have scheduled server restarts? I assume you have problems because the option is enabled (not disabled)? What are your actual server defaults? How do you set (I assume disable) the required value?

Comment: I am 100% sure there is nothing that sets it like that, however I do believe to haev narrowed it down to when apache2 restarts that it might set it to that mode. Which shouldn't happen, but as it's not live just yet I do play with some settings still (mainly for error reporting and logging atm)

Comment: enable logging. General Log. Then check it. So, save off the log, start with a fresh one. http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/mysql/5102/log-files/18052/general-query-log#t=201608101640266002631

Comment: @Hultin and did you find something please because I exactly have the same problem on my VPS hosted by OVH....